# cv_bridge accuracy?

Tags: cv-bridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS passes around images in its own sensor_msgs/image message format.
But it is 8bit data.
So I wiil want to use images in conhunction with OpenCV.
CvBridge is a ROS library that provides an interface between ROS and OpenCV.
Maybe Using cv_bridge is 32bit data.
Dose from 8bit to 32bit make loss accuracy?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42691/cv_bridge-accuracy?/) by [ha](https://answers.ros.org/users/2979/ha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-08-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS Image messages are not necessarily 8-bit data; the Image message supports a variety of encodings. (Note that the message uses an array of 8-bit values to store a binary blob; that doesn't mean it's 8-bit data.)

Unless you specifically tell it not to, cv_bridge will respect the type of the Image message it's operating on, and the resulting cv::Mat will match.

See the documentation on image_transport and cv_bridge for more.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2012-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/cv_bridge/Tutorials/UsingCvBridgeToConvertBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImages) at the cv_bridge tutorials and there are examples of what @Mac said.

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2012-09-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1